# Google Play Billing test card still shows up after production

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I have an app with in-app purchases which i used to test with the provided test card methods by google as shown here [Google Play Billing Test](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test)

However, after i published my app in production on Google Play, i still get the test card option. I can't use real cards to do the payment as shown below:

[image: Test cards]

I am not using my developer account to do the payment and the email of my google play is not listed in the licensed testers.

Can someone help to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I still see the test payment card when I am signed into the same Google account as I used to publish my app. Try signing out of your google account and signing into another account or try on another device that you have not signed in with your publishing account. I assume you have already done so but make sure you have uninstalled your debug version of you app and installed a fresh version from google play.

Hope this helps

Comment: Signing out and signing back in helped. Thank you so much

Comment: Question, so does this mean that if anyone has a test account that they could continue to make PROD purchases with the test card?! Is there any way to check for Test cards in a Production app to stop unlawful purchases!?

Comment: @Learn2Code Unless you have explicitly given someone access using one of the following methods, I don't think you should have any issues:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844686
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777
If you have given them access you should be able to revoke it too

Answer (score 1):

I had to go into the play console > Setup > License Testing and remove that email from the License testers section. Then I could make normal payments.